# Search and copy a specific part of a file to another file in Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, file, ifs

Suppose I have a text file with a lot of data. Using Shell Scripting, while reading the file if I get the keyword "CURRENT" it will copy the data to another file until it is getting the keyword "END-0".

Not able to develop the script snippet for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look at `awk` or `sed` for this task.

```
# Using SED
sed -n '/CURRENT/,/END-0/p' input-file >another-file

# Using AWK
awk '/CURRENT/,/END-0/' input-file >another-file
```